# Adding documents to a feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, editing, attachments, basic-license-level

I am using ArcMap 10.1 with a basic license.  It is my impression that the attachment feature has been upgraded to an advanced license.  My goal is to be able to add documents (ie. Land DEED) to a feature layer (parcel layer).

Is there any other work around that some knows of?

Comment: Yes, not available at basic level. 95% certain that this can be done using some efforts and Python. It is about creating additional table (6 fields, last is blob) and one relationship class

Comment: Didn't work, because of relationship. Alternative is to use hyperlink with relative path to the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workaround available at your license level is using hyperlinks.

To use hyperlinks from an attribute field, go into layer properties and select the display tab.  Tick the box 'Support Hyperlinks using field'.  Select the field that contains the paths to your hyperlinks.

[image]

To use dynamic hyperlinks, use the identify tool to identify each feature.  When the identify windows comes up, right click on the identified feature and select 'Add Hyperlink...'.  Navigate to and select your document (this must be done manually for each feature).

[image]
[image]

Comment: What data type should i use when i add a field?

Comment: The hyperlink field will be text and big enough to hold the path you want to put into it (254 is max for windows paths)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any workaround for this because the creation and editing of attachments involves the creation and editing of a relationship class. The latter is only available with a Standard or Advanced level license which means the same licensing is needed to create and edit attachments.

Comment: Relationship class is a wall. +1